# Unity: How do I get a 3D object to appear in my 2D game view? Main Camera settings are not the issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

3D Ring object for the positive balloon to float through

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are using a 3d mesh renderer in a orthographic camera.

Replace that object with a 2 sprite renderer, half shape of the ring to the left part with lower ordering layer and the other one with higher ordering layer. Then you can achieve that you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your solution. I actually did something like that before, but have them disabled if you look to the left, "hoop_left" and "hoop_right". However, I'm going to have them move across the screen and spawn infinitely as a prefab just like other two prefabs I have in the scene. Prefabs unfortunately count as 1 Gameobject and I can't get the balloon in between them. So this is why I'm experiment with 3D objects to achieve the effect.

Comment: But can create a empty game object and attach 2 gameobject inside with the 2 sprites, and put some collider at top and bottom to detect the colission if that the issue.
Then you can spawn as one prefab.
My recomendation is not use spawn infinitely, look about pools of objects so you can reuse enabling and disabling when you need one.

Comment: The Unity manual specifically mentions that you can perfectly use orthographic cameras with 3D meshes, so "you are using a 3d mesh renderer in a orthographic camera" is not the issue. If the mesh is occluded or is outside of the camera frame, it will not appear. This is true for Unity or any other engine.